# HTML-html code inside textbox

Tags: html

So basiclly, all I need to do is have a textbox on my website that displays HTML code for a picture in it.  I'm not sure how to do this without having it display the picture within the textbox.  I am scripting in HTML 4

*I Want The Code For The Image To Be Displayed, Not The Image

For example

```
<input type=text value="My Code Here">
```

I have tried

```
<input type=text value="<img src="logo100x100.png">">
```

Comment: pure content. Cant get any idea about what you asking

Comment: Can you post some code that you've tried

Comment: Not understood...please try to elaborate your query so that it iis understandable for all...ok

Comment: Are you trying to do this in .NET?

Comment: @Abdulla I added some information to it.  Hope that helped

Comment: @sinhayash I added an example and my code that I have tried

Comment: @Meghaa No, I'm sorry I should have clairified.  I am Scripting in HTML 4.  I just added it to my description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Using escape characters

`<input type=text value="&lt img src= &quot logo100x100.png &quot &gt">`
[image]

2. Using single quote and double quote separately

`<input type=text value='<img src="logo100x100.png">'>`

Comment: why? I have posted the output I'm getting in chrome

Comment: read question again plz **I Want The Code For The Image To Be Displayed, Not The Image**

Comment: Plz check the code is wrong. Their is starting of the double quotes but not the ending. @mas0701

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type=text value="<img src='logo100x100.png'>">
```

You can do this like this. I have also created a demo
https://jsfiddle.net/z5mLtykc/

[image]

Comment: I am trying to display the code for the image, not the image

Comment: Had you applied the above answer. It is showing code in the textbox, not the image.

Comment: Plz check the code is wrong of the answer you selected.. Their is starting of the double quotes but not the ending.  Mine answer id giving the correct result.@mas0701.

Comment: Both quotes are coming. Image was erroneous, which I changed. Thanks, your answer is also correct.